# Send an array to a Controller action via UrlParams

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, url-parameters

I have the action `ReportSsrs` of a `AffairesController`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ReportSsrs(
    int affaireId, 
    int[] coucheIds = null, 
    int[] secteurIds = null)
{
    return ...
}
```

I want to send an affair id and two arrays of ids `couche` and `secteur`

I try to use the following URL

```
//localhost:5001/affaires/reportssrs?affaireId=9&coucheIds[]=10&secteurIds[]=23
```

however what I get when I put a breakpoint and the action is hit, it does not seem to pass very well, the array value:
[image]

What is the correct way to pass an array via the URL to the action?

Comment: serialize those arrays before adding to the url

Comment: @J.Salas could you explain via an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct url should be:

```
localhost:5001/affaires/reportssrs?affaireId=9&coucheIds=10&secteurIds=10
```

If your array contains more than one item, the url should be:

```
[...]/reportssrs?affaireId=9&coucheIds=10&coucheIds=11&secteurIds=10&secteurIds=12
```

Comment: what if multiple values?

Comment: Hi @serge, it works fine and model binding binds the property by name. Did you add any custom middleware or model binding in your project? How do you configure the route template? You can add `[FromQuery]` to all the parameters to check if it works or not.